# HTAccess LocationMatch Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, live, local, locationmatch

I'm trying to use this `.htaccess` to change the `RewriteBase` if the location is local or live server.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

<LocationMatch "^/(bbtsrv02)/$">
    #RewriteBase /beta/admin/
</LocationMatch>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !css/(.*)\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !img/(.*)\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !incs/(.*)\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !js/(.*)\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !upload/(.*)\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !widget/(.*)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?_pd=$1 [NC,L]
```

As soon as I remove the `LocationMatch` the whole thing starts working again. I only need to change the `RewriteBase` for live testing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`<LocationMatch>` directive **CANNOT be used in .htaccess file** -- only in server config or virtual host context.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#locationmatch

Comment: Durrr. You know I even read this and told myself to take a mental note of that. Thanks for pointing it out again!

Comment: @James How do you access your local server? I guess via subfolders. If so -- why don't you fake DNS name (via `hosts` file) and access via domain name (e.g. `http://mysite.dev/`) .. so URL structure is the same as on live server?

Comment: we develop on a local server machine, which we all connect to individually. I've thought about setting up `hosts` file but it's a pain when we actually want to go live.

Comment: @James Then do it via your local DNS server (if you have it, of course) -- then will be no need to edit hosts file. BTW -- why _"it's a pain when we actually want to go live"_? You will have 1 domain name (real) for live server and local (different) name for local development -- I'm working like that all the time with no issues.