# Apache permissions based on querystring

Tags: apache, configuration, kerberos

I have an apache server where authentication is required, but there are some calls that need to be allowed for all.

On off these calls is based on a query string for example:

> /foo/api.php?Token=123&Task=DoStuff&Result=json

I taught that with a LocationMatch that this would have workd so i worked out this configuration:

```
<LocationMatch ^/foo/api.php\?.*(Task=DoStuff).*>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
</LocationMatch>
```

But this doesn't let me pass the authentication (meaning i get a 401).
If I just filter `^/foo/api.php` I get passed the authentication, but this isn't strict enough.

Anyone has any idea how to configure this to check the Task parameter in the querystring?

For authentication we are using kerberos, this is forced on the whole site
This is our conf for kerb

```
LoadModule auth_kerb_module modules/mod_auth_kerb.so

<Directory /var/www/html>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  AuthType Kerberos
  Require valid-user
  AuthName "Kerberos Login"
  KrbMethodNegotiate on
  KrbMethodK5Passwd on
  KrbAuthRealms FOO.LOCAL
  KrbServiceName HTTP/server.foo.local@foo.LOCAL
  Krb5KeyTab /etc/httpd/conf/http.keytab
  Satisfy Any
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 192.168.72.90
  Allow from 192.168.72.91
  Allow from 192.168.72.94
  Allow from 192.168.72.95
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can read [here](http://www.lucidiocy.com/2010/07/query-string-based-apache.html):

> The <Location>, <LocationMatch>, <Directory> and <DirectoryMatch>
> Apache directives allow us to apply authentication/authorization to
> specific patterns of resources with a high degree of specificity, **but
> do not give us that control down to the query-string level**.

Therefore, you have to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to achieve your goal.
For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Task=DoStuff
RewriteRule ^/foo/api.php - [E=no_auth_required:1]

<LocationMatch ^/foo/api.php>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from env=no_auth_required
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Login Required"
      AuthUserFile /var/www/foo/.htpasswd
      require valid-user
      Satisfy Any
</LocationMatch>
```

**UPDATE**

You've stated that:

> If I just filter ^/foo/api.php I get passed the authentication, but
> this isn't strict enough.

Then, try adding the following rows to your configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Task=DoStuff
RewriteRule ^/foo/api.php - [E=no_auth_required:1]

<LocationMatch ^/foo/api.php>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from env=no_auth_required
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: I will look into this, i should have added that we are using auth_kerb for authentication, the problem now i'm having is that he is doing auth_kerb first and then mod_rewrite

Comment: @Frederiek Is the `AuthType Kerberos` directive in your apache configuration file inside or outside the `LocationMatch` section? Can you eventually provide further details about the configuration that you are using? Maybe [this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/404149/how-can-i-disable-kerberos-authentication-for-only-the-root-of-my-site) could also be useful.

Comment: See edit in the original question. i have included the conf file

Comment: One thing to note is that LocationMatch cannot be used in .htaccess files - only in server config or virtual host context, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663611/htaccess-locationmatch-server-error

Answer (score 6):

In Apache **2.4** there's an easier way to do this without the rewrite.

You can use `LocationMatch` to match upto the `QUERY_STRING`, and then use an `If` block to match the contents of `QUERY_STRING`.  i.e., something like this:

```
<LocationMatch "^/foo/api.php">
  <If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /.*Task=DoStuff.*/" >
       Require all granted
  </If>
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: `<If>` is an apache 2.4 feature, and `Order`/`Allow` are apache 2.2 features. This could work if you use the Require syntax instead, but only on 2.4.

Answer (score -2):

we can't use `<If %{QUERY_STRING} /a=b/>`, is not supported by < apache 2.4

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} test=ok`

`RewriteRule ^/ - [E=checkParamTest:1]`

`<LocationMatch "^/">
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from env=checkParamTest
      Satisfy any
</LocationMatch>`

`<Location />
    AuthType openid-connect
    Require valid-user 
   ...
 </Location>`