# Limit access to an URL with query parameters

Tags: regex, apache, security, configuration

I need that an URL is accessible only for some defined users. In the URL there is a query parameter and that is the discriminator.

The URL could be something like this:

```
https://my.my.com/my-app/view/myView.xhtml?myQueryParam=allUsers
```

My experience in such apache configurations is ~ 0 and googling a little I could set up this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} myQueryParam=allUsers
RewriteRule "/my-app/view/myView[.]xhtml.*" - [E=no_auth_required:1]

<LocationMatch "/my-app/view/myView[.]xhtml.*">

               Require uniqueID user1ID user2ID

</LocationMatch>
```

Between `xhtml` and `?` could come additional strings too, therefor the `.*`.

This works but the problem is that it also denies the access for ex. to the link

```
https://my.my.com/my-app/view/myView.xhtml?myQueryParam=somethingElse
```

It seems that it doesn't bother the value of the query parameter...

What do I miss?

EDIT: I forgot to say that I use Apache 2.2.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648078/apache-permissions-based-on-querystring#?

Comment: What do you want for `myQueryParam=somethingElse` ?

Comment: Rewrite has always been a mystery to me. Does `.*` take you all the way up to `myQueryParam=allUsers` ?

Comment: weird, did you intend to do something with no_auth_required?

Comment: @revo for all other possible values of `myQueryParam` there are no restrictions.

Comment: @Phillip it is exactly the sample I used for my solution, but as I wrote it deny the access where `myQueryParameter != allUsers...

Comment: @covener as said I have 0 (zero) knowledge of such things. I based my on what I found in other thrads... :)

Comment: IMHO it's a bad idea to do this in the Apache config. (All the more as you say you have near zero experience in Apache setup.)  Better let the application define the authorization. Is the user authentication handled in Apache or in your application?

Comment: @gsl You are right. This would only be a fast and temporary solution until it is solved in the application.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Provided solution is for Apache v2.4</sup>

Check env variable value by an `If` directive within a `Location*` directive:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} myQueryParam=allUsers
RewriteRule . - [E=no_auth_required:1]

<Location "/my-app/view/myView.xhtml">
    <If "reqenv('no_auth_required') == 1">
        Require uniqueID user1ID user2ID
    </If>
</Location>
```

Comment: As said, unfortunately I use Apache 2.2. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try this, basically telling apache match anything after `xhtml` that is not a question mark.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} myQueryParam=allUsers
RewriteRule "/my-app/view/myView[.]xhtml[^?]*" - [E=no_auth_required:1]

<LocationMatch "/my-app/view/myView[.]xhtml[^?]*">

               Require uniqueID user1ID user2ID

</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it still denies the access also when `myQueryParam=something else`.